# Dynamically updating Bootstrap Modal with AJAX results without leave the modal or reload it's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to load a content dynamically from a Ajax call result in a Bootstrap Modal but I don't know how to or if it's possible. This is what I'm doing in my jQuery code:

```
$('button#btnBuscar').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.post(Routing.generate('filtrarNormas'), $('#buscadorNorma').serialize(), 'json')
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.entities.length > 1) {
                    $('#resultadoNorma').show();

                    var $html = '';
                    data.entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
                        $html += '<tr>';
                        $html += '<th><input type="checkbox" value="' + value.id + '"></th>';
                        $html += '<th>' + value.codigo + '</th>';
                        $html += '<th>' + value.norma + '</th>';
                        $html += '<th>' + value.anno + '</th>';
                        $html += '<th>' + value.comiteTecnico + '</th>';
                        $html += '</tr>';
                    });

                    $("#resultadoNormaBody").html($html);
                }
            })
            .fail();
});
```

And basically this is the modal (I remove some code for leave the post readable):

```
<div class="modal fade " id="addNorma" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNorma" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="buscadorNorma" method="POST">
                    // here goes some fields for search purpose
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" disabled="disabled" id="btnBuscar"><i class="fa fa-binoculars"></i> Buscar</button>
                <fieldset class="rpni-border" id="resultadoNorma" style="display: none">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Nro.</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>CT Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="resultadoNormaBody">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When any click the `button#btnBuscar` the `$.post` is triggered and then with the results in JSON format I should update dynamically the `#resultadoNormaBody`but my solution is not not working since I get not results in `#resultadoNormaBody` and also `fieldset#resultadoNorma` is never show, so I miss something, can any give me some help or tips on how to do this?

Ahhh important!! The modal should't be leave meaning should not be closed and reopened since then I'll lost the form values and that's wrong

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working" - work does and what doesn't work?

Comment: @TiesonT. done, I added to the latest paragraph take a look! And thanks for the tip

Comment: are you getting any console errors? also the request URL is in same domain?

Comment: Using Firebug or the native developer console in whatever browser(s) you're testing in, do you see an actual request being made? Are any errors logged in the console?

Comment: @CerlinBoss no, this is the problem I'm not getting any error and yes request URL is in the same domain

Comment: @TiesonT. yes, I see the request being executed (I use Firebug) and no errors in console tab is weird and I don't know why

Comment: Is `data` being returned as JSON? Otherwise, your loop is not executing, most likely, so `$html` is always an empty string. Use `console.log(data)` and `console.log($html)` to inspect both.

Comment: Ok, I found where the error is: `data.entities.length` always get 1 so the condition on my code `if (data.entities.length > 1)` will never be satisfied, just changing to `if (data.entities.length > 0)` did my code works to thanks @TiesonT. it works now